# ASP.Net MVC: How to populate view with model when loading view from DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i just read a article from this link http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/e544d1d3-e47e-4ced-bd4d-8c1eaefbdc31.aspx

they are loading view from db with static html but in real life we want data should come from model or view model.

now please tell me when we load view from db then how could i populate that view with my model data which i will supply at run time.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add  @model namespace_name.modelname in the view page

Comment: sorry do not understand from your explanation